# "I am going to take a shower"

Tags: verb

Would you say

> *Ich werde eine Dusche nehmen.*

or

> *Ich gehe eine Dusche nehmen.*

Which one is right for the sentence: "I am going to take a shower."

"I am going to take a shower" vs. "I will take a shower"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In German you do not take showers. - Instead you shower. Or shower yourself. Or go under the shower.

Why do you not take a shower? - I have heard of: "Ich nehme ein Bad." Why would you not do the same with a shower?

Because a shower is pretty immaterial. It is hard to grasp.

If you want to use the word take. You could say.

> Ich **nehme** es auf mich, jetzt Duschen zu gehen. Or "zu Duschen."
>
> I now **take** it upon me to go for a shower.

But this way you would be expressing taking a shower being a burden. Which it usually is not. (for most people)

So what you say instead is to just express what you are "going" to do. You are going "under the shower." You are "going" to work. (by car, train, bus, plane, boat)

You say one of the following phrases:

> Ich gehe unter die Dusche.
>   Ich gehe in die Dusche.
>   Ich gehe mich duschen.
>   Ich gehe duschen.
>   Ich gehe zum Duschen (ins Hallenbad).
>   Ich dusche (mich mal kurz).
>   Ich bin (am) Duschen.
>   Ich bin (beim) Duschen.

Comment: You should also mention "Ich bin duschen." and "Ich dusche."

Comment: @maja, added some "()" brackets to highlight the phrases you suggested.

Answer (score 13):

**Neither.**

The most common way to describe announce the intention of taking a shower would be

> Ich gehe duschen.

The noun **Dusche** is used for describing the place and devices/fittings/plumbings required for taking a shower, but rarely (if ever) for the activity.

Another possibility would be

> Ich gehe kurz unter die Dusche.

---

For taking a bath it is ok:

> Ich nehme ein Bad.

This would be unusual (sound a bit formal) in spoken language here in Austria too, and would imply that you take some time to relax instead of just getting clean. We tend to prefer

> Ich gehe baden.

for everyday use.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers that i agree to:

In the English language `will` expresses rather that you intend to do something but that might change whereas `going to` means that one is very concerned about doing something and will do so if nothing unexpected stops him/her from doing so.

There is no way to express this difference with a few words in German.

And, as said, one does not `take` a shower in German; one showers. The phrase `Ich nehme eine Dusche` could be used in a shop to express that you want to *buy* a shower.

Comment: Are you sure about the English meaning? Because I always thought that the difference is that "going to" is the immediate future (the future equivalent to present perfect), while "will" is the general future (the future equivalent to simple past).

Comment: I agree that will is a more general term; i've been told about this difference by my english teacher. It is the best of my knowledge even though i am not very concerned about it.